# Use increased priority for sockets communication in .NET?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a C# application that uses System.Net.Sockets.Socket to communicate with some devices on a local network, each time that a message is sent from the application to a device an acknowledge from the device is expected - usually within 200 milliseconds, if the acknowledge is not received within a given timeout period an exception is thrown.

There is one socket per device

Reception is by the socket ReceiveAsync method.

Some users report seeing the acknowledge timeout exception even though I have increased the timeout period to one second, my worry is that the users may be running another application that is cpu intensive and thus interfering with the reception of packages from the devices.

Should I consider raising the priority of my application or does .NET already assign an increased priority to socket events or is the systems time slice for each thread short enough that I do not need to worry about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Networks performance can take a "burp" and have a performance hit all the time regardless of the process priority.

With that in mind, 1 second is a really short timeout interval.   You didn't say TCP or UDP.  For TCP, I'd wait longer - much longer. For UDP, add retry logic.

Users don't want to see exceptions.  They want to see the application working.

Comment: We are using TCP on a dedicated local network that has no other devices and it's own network adapter, the exception is thrown because I would not expect a 'burp' of one second on such a system. Pinging a device takes less than one millisecond.